# How to have a dynamic width for a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, width, jframe, jtextfield

I have a `JFrame` with a `JTextField`.  I want to get the width of the `JTextField`  increased/decreased accordingly when the `JFrame` is maximized/restored.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a component listener to the JFrame. It provides some methods to run when the component is resized, moved, hidden or shown. [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) is how to do it.

Comment: You **really** shouldn't need to use listeners to get your components to resize when the parent is resized.  If you find yourself using this you should bite the bullet and learn how to use a LayoutManager properly.  In fact, the example code in the tutorial you link to **has a textbox that takes up all available space**, and you'll notice it doesn't use the component listener to do so.

Comment: Yeah that's right. LayoutManager is useful in most cases, but in one of school projects, I had to change not the size of components but the layout itself when the window is resized. Though I'm not a Swing guru and my project was not large-scale to learn Swing completely, my solution was using that kind of listener. (Right now, @user805563 doesn't replied yet, and we don't know if s/he needs to change layout, or doesn't know how to use layouts efficiently. :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a LayoutManager for the parent component which instructs the JTextField to fill up available space.

The default layout manager for a JFrame will do this however.  If you simply call `frame.add(new JTextField())` and try to resize the window, the text field **will** fill the available space.  You must be putting the JTextField into an intermediate panel which has a different layout manager.  You would need to give more context for us to help you with your specific problem.

Comment: +1, another option would be to register a `ComponentListener` and override the [`componentResized(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized%28java.awt.event.ComponentEvent%29) method to perform some custom action(s).

Comment: @user805563: The tutorial you want to read starts here: [Laying out Components in a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)